# clGetPlatformInfo Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, opencl

I have a simple main.cpp file that uses openCL. (see at the end)
I am using bash under Windows 10 Linux Subsystem (Ubuntu 14) to make things easier for me (i think) so I don't have to use mingw or something on windows.

Anyways, I compile that simple main.cpp file using the following:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -I "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/AMD APP SDK/3.0/include" -L "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/AMD APP SDK/3.0/lib/x86_64" -lOpenCL
```

I get segmentation fault when i try to run the program. It occurs on line 33 (error = clGetPlatformIDs)

**Main.CPP**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef APPLE
#include <OpenCL/cl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif

void displayPlatformInfo(cl_platform_id id, cl_platform_info param_name, const char* paramNameAsStr)
{
  cl_int error = 0;
  size_t paramSize = 0;

  error = clGetPlatformInfo( id, param_name, 0, NULL, &paramSize);

  char* moreInfo = (char*)alloca(sizeof(char)*paramSize);
  error = clGetPlatformInfo( id, param_name, paramSize, moreInfo, NULL);

  if (error != CL_SUCCESS) {
    perror("Unable to find any OpenCL Plaform Information");
    return;
  }
  printf("%s: %s\n", paramNameAsStr, moreInfo);
}

int main() {

  cl_platform_id* platforms;
  cl_uint numOfPlatforms;
  cl_int error;

  error = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numOfPlatforms);
  if (error <0 ) {
    perror("Unable to find any openCL Platforms");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("Number of OpenCL platform found: %d\n",numOfPlatforms);
  platforms = (cl_platform_id*) alloca(sizeof(cl_platform_id)* numOfPlatforms);

  for (cl_uint i = 0; i < numOfPlatforms; ++i) {
    displayPlatformInfo( platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE,   "CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE");
    displayPlatformInfo( platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_VERSION,   "CL_PLATFORM_VERSION");
    displayPlatformInfo( platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_NAME,      "CL_PLATFORM_NAME");
    displayPlatformInfo( platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR,    "CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR");
    displayPlatformInfo( platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS,"CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's to be expected, the only intention of the Linux subsystem was to make bash work.  Google "linux subsystem limitations" to learn more.

Comment: I guess it was. Thanks for the answer. Also I am missing a call to clGetPlatformInfo to initialize stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Put a value for the platforms.

A value greater than the number of platforms found.

Example:

```
numOfPlatforms = 10;
```